# Which one is best to create multiple object but it should not affect performance?

Tags: java, performance

I have a scenarios to create the multiple object. I feel If i create multiple object as below it will cause performance issue. Is there any alternative to create multiple Mark object? Or If it's not, which one is best to create Mark object in this 2 cases? Or Both are same?

```
List<Student> list = getStudentList();

Case 1:
Mark mark = null;
for(Student s : student) {
   mark = new Mark();
}

Case 2:
for(Student s : student) {
  Mark mark = new Mark();
}
```

***Could you please suggest me?***

Comment: Both allocate the same number of `Mark` objects, so their performance will likely be the same. Though in 2, it's clear that the `mark` instance won't be used outside of the loop, while in 1 it might be.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two approaces are about readability and scope. If you're not gonna use the objects you create outside the for loop, then you should prefer the 2nd approach, which won't pollute the outer scope.

Their performance will be the same because the compiler will produce the exact same bytecode for both of them in your example.